# Get address of contract

Tags: solidity, addresses

Is this the right way to get the address of a Contract, that is stored inside another contract:

Example:

```
import "B.sol";
contract A{
    B private bContract;
    construtor(){}

    function setBContract(address _address) {
        bContract = new B(_address);
    }

    function getBAddress() returns(address){
        return address(bContract);
    }

}
```

Or do I have to save the address in some variable like so:

```
function setBContract(address _address) {
    bContract = new B(_address);
    bAddress = _address;
}
```

And then just retrieve it over the `bAddress` variable? Or is it exactly the same?

And which one ist the preffered way? (gas wise).
I assume storing another value will cost more?

Comment: The first one, less gas as u said